# Damage to shocks over sharp curb

Tags: wheels, kia, struts, sportage

I drive a 2012 Sportage and I accidentally drove over the curb yesterday. The bricks that made this curb where old and irregular so there we sharp bits poking out. I was not driving too fast but as soon as I went over it I heard a massive boom like my tyre exploded. I pulled to the side, noticed I had a completely flat front left tyre and changed it with the spare. I examined the ruined tyre and there was a hole 1 inch by 1 inch on the sidewall. I drove back and noticed I had to turn my wheel around 30 degrees to the right to drive straight so in other words my wheel alignment was completely disrupted. Took a look at the wheel and the top was slanted inward. The wheel is fixed fine there is nothing wrong there, I think I have damaged the shocks or the struts when going over a sharp part of the curb. How can I be sure this is the case? What else could be wrong? 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! We cannot tell you cost, because it's off-topic for the site. As for as the rest, I'd bet the shock is okay. If you cannot discern any fluid leakage nor does it look like the shaft is bent or the body deformed in some way, it's probably going to be okay. I'd suggest you get a new tire and get the alignment done (you know it needs both of these). Then see how it goes. I bet you'll be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The spare tyre is a month old and I made sure it was properly aligned when I bought it.

Comment: Take it in for a front end alignment, they should find any damage.